# OBIEE 11g - How do I create a crosstab from a data table?

Tags: obiee

When I run my Analysis, I have data that looks like this:

```
Name               Class ID  Class Date
Jones, Joe         241-A     2020-10-01
                   561-D     2020-10-15
                   106-C     2020-09-16
Williams, Sara     241-A     2020-11-04
                   561-D     2020-12-01
                   106-C     2020-09-22
Bonney, Jim        241-A     2020-11-15
                   561-D     2020-12-04
Furter, Frank N.   241-A     2020-12-12
                   561-D     2020-09-18
                   106-C     2020-10-06
```

.. and I'd like to format it this way:

```
                241-A        561-D        106-C
Jones, Joe      2020-10-01   2020-10-15   2020-09-16
Williams, Sara  2020-11-04   2020-12-01   2020-09-22
etc.
```

I tried to use `FILTER("Facts"."Username" USING ("eInfo"."ClassID" = '241-A'))` but it gave me the error message: **Function FILTER requires at least one measure column in its first argument.**

In my data I don't have any dollar amounts -- All my numeric data fields are either an ID or a Date.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a table view. Just use a Pivot view and drag your "Name" into the rows and your "Class ID" into the columns part of the pivot. Done.

Don't think code first. try to understand how the tool works. A pivot is quite literally the most basic functionality and using code to achieve this is a bad sign for any future thing that gets attempted. Learn the product first or you will badly abuse it and produce sub-par results.